# SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

the full error message goes like

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`phinder`.`storage`, CONSTRAINT `FK63lhdaxtuokuwqrojm6ue9qsh` FOREIGN KEY (`address_address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`address_id`))

My pharmacy class looks like

```
public class Pharmacy {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long pharmacyId;
  private String pharmacyName;
  private Double latitude;
  private Double longitude;
  private boolean isOpen;
  private boolean isPrivate;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<User> users;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Storage> storage;
}
```

My Adress class looks like

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long addressId;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String subCity;
    private String woreda;
    private String houseNumber;
```

My Storage Class looks like

```
@Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long storageId;
  private String storageName;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;
  private Long pharmacyId;
  private Boolean isEnabled;
```

and the error is caused when i try to run the function below where it creates a new pharmacy object the creates a new storage and then assigns the storage to the pharmacy and then saves the pharmacy and due to cascade should save the rest of the objects

```
public Pharmacy addPharmacy(Pharmacy pharmacy) {
        Pharmacy registeredPharmacy = pharmacyRepo.save(pharmacy);
        Storage storage = new Storage(
            registeredPharmacy.getPharmacyName(),
            registeredPharmacy.getPharmacyId(),
            AddressCopier.copyObjectWithoutField(registeredPharmacy.getAddress(), "addressId"),
            true
        );
        Set<Storage> storages = new HashSet<>();
        storages.add(storage);
        registeredPharmacy.setStorage(storages);
        return pharmacyRepo.save(registeredPharmacy);
    }
```

i have tried the other answers to similar questions like saving the address first before saving the storage and pharmacy but i still get the same error and its not working so it'd be wonderful if someone helps